# Is It Possible To Set Up A Single Ajax Call For Numerous Inputs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In a php file I have a form tag with numerous inputs of type submit (so they’re basically buttons) and they were created automatically by an outside php script (so they have names like button0, button1, etc.). I am trying to use ajax and jQuery to, on click, send the value of the clicked button to a database using another php script.

I’m kind of new to ajax. The way I understand the syntax that I’m using is that you would write something like this:

```
$.post('phpScripts/whateverFile.php', {name: value}).done(function(data){//do something});
```

(The above would be put in the callback function of the listener of a click event in the submit button I’m talking about; yes, I made sure to use e.preventDefault())

For example, if I have a single button like this:

```
<input type = "Submit" name = "button0" value = "Button0"></input>
```

I could send that to be taken care of by the php file using post like this:

```
$.post('phpScripts/whateverFile.php', {button0: $(this).val()}).done(function(data){//do something});
```

Remember, because it is part of an event listener I attached to the button itself, I can use this to reference it (or so I figure).

And in the php file I could have something like this:

```
    if(isset($_POST['button0']))
    {
      //do whatever
    }
```

My question is: how would I go about writing the ajax for NUMEROUS submit buttons with the same event listener? That is, they all have the same class, and I just do this:

```
$('.sameClass').click(function(e){//ajax function in here});
```

The way I’m currently doing it works with a single button. Now, I tried making the names unique by putting each in a variable and replacing the actual name with the variable like this:

```
var buttonName = $(this).attr('name');

$.post('phpScripts/whateverFile.php', {buttonName:$(this).val()}).done(function(data){console.log(data);});
```

But that didn’t work and I am now hopelessly out of ideas. Any ideas of how I can do this? Is it even possible? How do I make it so that when I click each of these submit buttons, some unique data is sent based on the button?

Your help is greatly appreciated…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not wise to have an `if else` block for multiple buttons. If you had 10 buttons, then you would have to make 10 `if/ else` blocks. It get's really inefficient.

My solution would be - to assign the same class to the buttons.

```
<button class="my_btn" name="button1" value="1">1</button>
<button class="my_btn" name="button2" value="2">2</button>
<button class="my_btn" name="button3" value="3">3</button>
```

Then in the ajax call pass in the value and name of the button:

```
$(".my_btn").click(function(){
    const btn_val = $(this).val(); //gets the value of the current clicked button
    const btn_name = $(this).attr('name');

    $.ajax({
        url 'phpScripts/whateverFile.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {btn_val, btn_name},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    })

});
```

In server side/ php, you just have a single if block. You are then able to know there is a post data coming from the button click, and you also know which button it came from.

```
if (isset($_POST["btn_val"])) {
    echo $_POST["btn_val"] . "is from btn name: " . $_POST["btn_name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change input type to button and add class to each of your html buttons.

```
<input type="button" name="button1" class="myButton" value="Button1"/>
<input type="button" name="button2" class="myButton" value="Button2"/>
<input type="button" name ="button3" class="myButton" value="Button3"/>
<input type="button" name ="button4" class="myButton" value="Button4"/>
```

And submit data with ajax call,

```
$(function(){
$('input.myButton').click(function(e) {
    var button_value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url : 'whateverFile.php',
    type: 'post',
        data : {button_value:button_value},
        success: function(data) {
        //do something
        },
        error: function() {
        // do sometihing
        }
     });
```

Just verify on the server side by var_dump($_POST).